# How to write a C program for a Fibonacci like sequence without vectors/recursion?

Tags: c, math, logic

The sequence I'm trying to achieve is similar to Fibonacci but instead of the Nth number being `N-1 + N-2` we have a `K` value and the Nth number will be `N-1 + N-2 + ... + N-K`.

I want to write a C program to write the sequence until the Nth number with `K` and `N` as input. It MUST NOT use vectors or recursion.

**Update:**

There is no possible solution, it was an exercise to prove the necessity of a vector (array) into a solution of some problems.

Comment: What vectors? There are no vectors in C...Use a loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: In context, it's pretty clear (at least to me) that "vector" is being used as another name for an array.  Most of my old CS professors had Math degrees, and used the term "vector" for 1D arrays in Fortran and C.  Basically, the problem statement forbids using arrays as intermediate storage.

Comment: Does this exclude any array or only the array to store the full sequence? I.e., is a working array for the last `K` values permissible?

Comment: It does exclude any array.

Comment: Can you provide a example series with values of K, N; lets say for first 10 terms, so that we can help you provide algorithm to compute (N+10)th element of the series.

Comment: For K = 3 and N = 7 : 1,1,1,3,5,9,17. For K = 4 and N = 10 : 1,1,1,1,4,7,13,25,49,94

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to not be a real question but rather was a homework "gotcha" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real answer as it was a deadend question.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of storage for (at least) the previous `K` values, and I presume that the crux of your question is what you can use for that.

You cannot use the call stack / function parameters because you must not recurse.  You cannot use a "vector", by which I suppose you mean an array.  It would be extremely messy to use individual local variables, and not really feasible to do so at all unless there were a very low bound on the values `K` may take.  The only alternatives I see are

1. Some flavor of linked list.  (But be careful -- a linked list might be considered a "vector" in a very loose sense of that term.)
2. An external file.  (Yuck!)

Likely this exercise is related to what you've been studying in class, so that should give you a clue of what the instructor has in mind.

I leave the actual implementation as the exercise that it is.

Comment: It cannot be an external file as we did not learnt it yet. In the first option wouldn't I have to manually write a list for every K value? That won't work as K can be any integer.

Comment: @emiliopedrollo, no, you would not have to write a separate list for each `K` value.  Having flexible length is one of the primary characteristics of a linked list.  You would need only one list implementation if you took that approach -- you would just have to apply it to your problem in a suitable way.

Comment: So, a linked list is a approach using pointer right? Well, we didn't see that yet at class, so I presume that's not the intended solution. By now I'm starting to think there's no way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - this is **not**, I repeat **NOT** what your professor is looking for, but...

If you know how to solve [recurrence relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html), you could find the *closed form* of the relation for each value of `K` and simply compute that (no loop, no storage of intermediate values).  For example, the *n<sup>th</sup>* Fibonacci number can be computed using the function

```
long double fib_closed( unsigned int n )
{
  long double sqrt_5 = sqrtl(5.0);
  long double    phi = (1 + sqrt_5) / 2.0;
  long double    psi = (1 - sqrt_5) / 2.0;

  return floorl( (powl( phi, n ) - powl( psi, n )) / sqrt_5 );
}
```

In your case, you'd have a different recurrence relation for each `K` (that is, the recurrence relation for N-1 + N-2 + N-3 will be different from the recurrence relation for N-1 + N-2 + N-3 + N-4, etc. ), so you'd need to write as many functions as values of `K` you'd want to use:

```
switch( K )
{
  case 3: return f_closed_3( n ); break;
  case 4: return f_closed_4( n ); break;
  ...
}
```

which, thinking about it, is not going to be terribly practical.  Again, this is **not** what your professor is looking for, but it may make for an interesting exercise some time in the future.

Comment: That way I will have to find/write a relation for every K value, which ranges from 1 to positive infinity. So not feasible.